# AngularJS Summernote insert link always open in new tab by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, summernote, ng-dialog

I have a Summernote editor in an `ng-dialog` and I'm trying to make all links that are inserted open in a new tab by default. I added a CSS class to the editor to hide the checkbox for that option but I can't figure out a way to check that checkbox.

Is there an insertLink or dialogOpen event that I can place my code for checking the checkbox? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the summernote.js file and find

```
$openInNewWindow.prop('checked', linkInfo.isNewWindow);
```

Set this forcefully true by replacing linkInfo.isNewWindow

```
$openInNewWindow.prop('checked', true);
```

Hopefully it will resolve your issue.